# Trying to PUSH a value in ASM inside a function, what do I do wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I am just learning ASM and I am coding in Visual Studio (I am including the ASM in the C++ code).
The problem I am trying to solve: I have a number. I have to convert it to base 4 and then convert it to char array. 
I did manage to convert it but backwards (if the number is 1332(4) i get 2331(4) in the char array) and now I wanted to reverse it. 
I am stuck when I try to PUSH a value inside the function. When I am trying to access it (CMP EDI, [EBP + 16]), I don't get the right value. This is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void conv(unsigned n, char* s);
int zero = 0;
int unu = 1;
int doi = 2;
char s[25];
int po = 48;

int main()
{
    unsigned n = 126;
    _asm
    {
        LEA ECX, s
        PUSH ECX
        PUSH n
        CALL conv
        ADD ESP, 8
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cout << s[i] << " ";
}

void conv(unsigned n, char* s)
{
    _asm {
        MOV EBX, [EBP + 12]
        MOV ECX, [EBP + 8]
        MOV EDI, zero
        //fac sirul invers
        lopp :
            CMP ECX, zero
            JBE endd
            SHR ECX, 1
            MOV EDX, zero
            JC gasit1
            JMP nextt
            gasit1 :
             ADD EDX, unu
            nextt :
            SHR ECX, 1
            JC gasit12
            ADD EDX, zero
            JMP next2
            gasit12 :
            ADD EDX, doi
            next2 :
            ADD EDX, po
            MOV [EBX + EDI], EDX
            MOV EDX, 0
            INC EDI
            JMP lopp
            endd:
                DEC EDI
                MOV ESI, EDI
                MOV eax, edi
                div doi
                PUSH EAX
                revertt:
                    CMP EDI, [EBP + 16]
                    JBE finall
                    MOV AH, byte ptr [EBX + EDI]
                    MOV EDX, ESI
                    SUB EDX, EDI
                    MOV CH , byte ptr [EBX + EDX]
                    PUSH ECX
                    MOV [EBX + EDX], AH
                    POP ECX
                    MOV [EBX + EDI], CH
                    DEC EDI
                JMP revertt
                finall:
                    ADD ESP, 4
    }
}
```

Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with `[ebp+16]`. That is not in your stack frame. The `PUSH ECX` / `POP ECX` pair makes no sense as the only thing between them doesn't even change `ECX`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I've just realised that ECX isn't changing. I must be blind. I changed the code to work replacing that line (CMP EDI, [EBP+16] ) with something else but I still don't understand why it is a wrong value at [EBP+16] when I try to access it. I guess I am not sure how this works. I wanted to see if I can keep the value where I need to stop the loop on Stack so that's why I did that.

Comment: If you want to use `[ebp+12]` and stuff directly, use a [`__declspec(naked)` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/naked-cpp?view=vs-2019) and write everything (including frame pointer setup/teardown and ret) yourself.  Otherwise it's recommended to access function args by their C++ variable names and let the compiler worry about the stack frame.  It can even inline functions that contain an `_asm` block.

Comment: Also, note that base 4 is a power of 2, so each base-4 digit depends *only* on 2 bits of the input number.  See [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) for an efficient way to do that without any push/pop reverse loop.  Your code looks very over-complicated, and you definitely don't need to use global variables for values like `1` and `'0'` that could be immediates in the asm.  :/

Comment: Thank you, I will try to keep that in mind. Also thank you for the link, I really wanted to find a more efficient way to do the converting and this is what I needed.